# Intra class correlation and experimental design

Tags: correlation, sampling

I am trying to understand how to apply the [intraclass correlation coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intraclass_correlation_coefficient).

The situation we have is the following: we have $k$ judges who can assign numerical ratings to targets, and we want to test the reliability and consistency of these judges. One of the judges is considered to be an expert. So we pick $n$ targets, and each of the $k$ judges judges all $n$ targets twice, so we have $2nk$ measurements per experiment. Each judgement is somewhat expensive and takes a long time, so we do not want to make a judge do any more work than strictly necessary. The situation is as in [case 3 as explained in section *Models for Reliability Studies* in Shrout and Fleiss.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1037%2F%2F0033-2909.86.2.420)

Then we compare each judge to herself when rating the same target, so that's $n$ intra-ratings per judge, and we compare each judge to the expert judge, which is $2n$ inter-ratings per judge. There is no inter-rating for the expert. Then we compute an inter and an intra ICC using the following numpy code:

```
from numpy import isnan, nan, logical_not, logical_or

def exclude_nan(x,y):
    """
    Exclude NaN values if either entry in a pair of vectors has NaN
    """
    idx = logical_not(logical_or(isnan(x), isnan(y)))
    x = x[idx]
    y = y[idx]
    n = len(x)
    return [x, y, n]

def compute_icc(x, y):
    """
    This function computes the intra-class correlation (ICC) of the
    two classes represented by the x and y numpy vectors.
    """

    if all(x == y):
        return 1

    [x, y, n] = exclude_nan(x, y)

    ## Need at least 3 data points to compute this
    if n < 3:
        return nan

    Sx = sum(x); Sy = sum(y);
    Sxx = sum(x*x); Sxy = sum((x+y)**2) / 2; Syy = sum(y*y)

    fact = ((Sx + Sy)**2) / (n*2)
    SS_tot = Sxx + Syy - fact
    SS_among = Sxy - fact
    SS_error = SS_tot - SS_among

    MS_error = SS_error / n
    MS_among = SS_among / (n-1)

    ICC = (MS_among - MS_error) / (MS_among + MS_error)

    return ICC
```

This corresponds to $\operatorname{ICC}(3,1)$ in Shrout & Fleiss linked above.

The question now is, what $n$ should we pick? Making the same assumptions as in Case 3 of Shrout & Fleiss, what are the statistical properties of the ICC estimator?